# Converting $_SESSION variables in normal variables in php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to pass all the variables stored in SESSION independent variables as follows:

```
<?php

session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 'off');


$vars = array('id','name','mail1','mail2','phone1','phone2','address','genere',
                        'departament','tittle' );
    foreach ($vars as $v) {
            if (isset($_SESSION[$v])) {
                $$vars[v]= $_SESSION[$v];
                echo $$vars[v].'<br />';
            }
        }
    echo $name;
    echo </ br>;            
    echo $mail1;


?>
```

but when I try to print the contents of a variable, apparently is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have missed a ' at `genere'`, is that an error when trying to paste the code here?

Comment: `${$v} = $_SESSION[$v];` should work but not recommended because of security issues and such. I'd just stick with `$_SESSION` variable if I were you

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger nice name, yes was an error when i paste the code..

Comment: @Class You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Use `extract($_SESSION)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
extract($_SESSION)
echo $id;
echo $name;
// so on ...
```

Ref : https://www.php.net/extract

PLEASE CHECK THE WARNING NOTE GIVEN IN THE DOCUMENTATION

OR

```
foreach ($vars as $v) {
    if (isset($_SESSION[$v])) {
         $$v= $_SESSION[$v];
         echo $$v.'<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your code has error only change the line after isset function like that:

```
<?php
$$v = $_SESSION[$v];    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then storing your variables individually you should store them in an array. That way you'll have access to the only variable you need.

Something like below:

```
$_SESSION['details'] = array();
$_SESSION['details']['name'] = 'xxx';
$_SESSION['details']['id'] = 'xxx';
$_SESSION['details']['mail1'] = 'xxx';
$_SESSION['details']['mail2'] = 'xxx';
$_SESSION['details']['phone1'] = 'xxx';
```

And now to access them individually you can simply do this.

```
extract($_SESSION['details']);
echo $name;
echo $id;
```